# Activeadmin - form inside show page are displaying only submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm working on a project using using Ruby-2.5.5 , Rails 5.2.2.1, and Activeadmin 1.4.3

On Activeadmin `resort` show page, I'm trying to add a form to update specific fields in `resort`. So far I added the following inside `show do`

```
show do
    ...
    div do
        semantic_form_for [:admin, resort], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f|
            f.inputs do
                f.input :name
                f.input :description
            end
            f.actions
        end
    end
end
```

However, what I get is just `Update Resort` button as displayed:

[image]

Any ideas how to display the input fields?